# How can I retrieve a list of available versions for a specific library compatible with a certain Python version?

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, version

I'm currently working on a project in Python and need to ensure compatibility between a specific library and a particular Python version. To achieve this, I want to create a Python script that retrieves and displays a list of all available versions of a library that can be installed for a given Python version.

For instance, let's say my project is using Python 3.8, and I want to check the available versions of the `numpy` library that are compatible with this Python version. How can I write a script that leverages the Python Package Index (PyPI) API or any relevant method to fetch and showcase a list of `numpy` versions that I can consider for installation using `pip`?

I believe having such a script will greatly aid in managing version compatibility and making informed decisions about library installations. If anyone could provide me with a sample script that accomplishes this task that would be great.

Comment: _I want to check the available versions of the numpy library that are compatible with this Python version_ Why wouldn't you use the latest compatible version?  Why would you even care about earlier versions?  It sounds like you have other requirements that you haven't stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PyPI API to fetch information about the available versions of a library. Here's a sample script that retrieves the versions of numpy compatible with a specific Python version:

```py
import requests

python_version = '3.8'
library_name = 'numpy'

url = f'https://pypi.org/pypi/{library_name}/json'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

release_data = data['releases']
available_versions = []
for version, releases in release_data.items():
    for release in releases:
        if str(release['python_version']).startswith(python_version):
            available_versions.append(version)

if available_versions:
    print(f"Available versions of {library_name} compatible with Python {python_version}:\n")
    for version in available_versions:
        print(f"- {version}")
else:
    print(f"No versions of {library_name} available for Python {python_version}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
import requests


current_python_version = "".join(sys.version.split(" ")[0].split(".")[:2])
library = "numpy"

url = f"https://pypi.org/pypi/{library}/json"

with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url=f"https://pypi.org/pypi/{library}/json")
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())

data = response.json()
releases = pd.json_normalize(data=data["releases"]).columns.tolist()

compatible_versions = (pd
                       .concat([pd.json_normalize(data=data["releases"], record_path=x) for x in releases])
                       .query(expr="python_version.str.contains(@current_python_version)")
                       .filter(items=["filename"])
                       .assign(filename=lambda x: x.filename.str.split("-").str[1]).filename.unique().tolist()
                       )
print(f"{compatible_versions = }")
```

Output:

```
compatible_versions = ['1.23.2', '1.23.3', '1.23.4', '1.23.5', '1.24.0', '1.24.0rc1', '1.24.0rc2', '1.24.1', '1.24.2', '1.24.3', '1.24.4', '1.25.0', '1.25.0rc1', '1.25.1', '1.25.2', '1.26.0b1']
```